# Where is the HttpConflict in MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a C++ guy with no "web stuff" experience, but my supervisors want me to go learn the ways of "ASP.NET MVC 6", because it's the latest snazzy thing.

I managed to get a hold of at least one tutorial, but I see no reference and no documentation anywhere. Where do I look up what classes and methods there are?

My current problem is that I am trying to figure out how to return a Http status of 409 from my Create method in my controller. I don't see a HttpConflict method. What do I call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP MVC 6 you can return an instance of the [`StatusCodeResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/StatusCodeResult.cs) from your controller method:

```
public IActionResult ConflictAction()
{
    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
}
```

Better yet, you could create your own **`HttpConflictResult`** class:

```
public class HttpConflictResult : StatusCodeResult
{
    public HttpConflictResult() : base(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)
    {
    }
}

public IActionResult ConflictAction()
{
    return new HttpConflictResult();
}
```

In case you are wondering, those result types are just setting the `StatusCode` property of the response, so the following would be equivalent to the 2 approaches above based on `StatusCodeResult`:

```
public IActionResult ConflictAction()
{
    Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict;
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Where is this HttpStatusCodeResult method?  The link you gave is dead and I can't find it in the libraries.

Comment: It was renamed to `StatusCodeResult`. I've just updated the answer and links

Answer (score 6):

With ASP.NET Core 1.0 you can use the `StatusCode(int statusCode)` method available on any `Controller`.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Widget item)
{
  // ...

  // using the HttpStatusCode enum keeps it a little more readable
  return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Conflict); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [HttpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx)

Namespaces

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
```

You use it like

```
public HttpResponseMessage ConflictSample()
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Conflict");
}
```

Comment: request - what the hell is it?

Comment: Thanks :). It's worth noting also that you'll also need a reference for Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string sequenceId)
    {                     
            var response = new ContentResult()
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status409Conflict,
                Content = "Order duplicate"
            };
            return response;           
    }
```

I think this is a cleaner way